# How to add an attribute to a KeyValuePair in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, attributes

I want to do this but keep getting syntax error:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> websters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{            
    [Attrib(xx)]
    {"SortIdxUnitLocation", "Int32"},
    [Attrib(yy)]
    {"DepartmentID" , "String"}, 
    [Attrib(zz)]
    {"Department" , "String"}
};
```

Is it not possible or is special syntax needed?

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but it's not possible in any languages that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by your code that it's C#, and no it's not possible.  Attributes can only be bound to compile time constructs like classes, fields, method, properties, etc.  If you want to store some additional information with your dictionary entries then you probably need a different data structure as the value part of the key-value pair.